# Unable to add screenshot in ReportNG HTML report

Tags: selenium, testng, reportng

I am trying to take a screenshot for failure methods and also want to put the same in my Report, I am able to take the screenshot but unable to show the same in HTML report. Following is my code, friends any clue on this ?

```
public class SB1 {
    private static  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SB1.class);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@Test
public void Testone() {

    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

    assert false;




}


public void catchExceptions(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("result" + result);
    String methodName = result.getName();
    System.out.println(methodName);

    if (!result.isSuccess()) {

        try {

        String failureImageFileName =  new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-ss").format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime())+ ".png"; 
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(failureImageFileName)); 

            String userDirector = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/"; 
            Reporter.log("<a href=\""+ userDirector + failureImageFileName +"\"><img src=\"file:///" + userDirector 
                         + failureImageFileName + "\" alt=\"\""+ "height='100' width='100'/> "+"<br />"); 
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(null); 

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set ESCAPE_PROPERTY to false? This is what you will have to do if you want reportng to post the screenshot -

```
    private static final String ESCAPE_PROPERTY = "org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output";
```

and in your setUp-

```
    System.setProperty(ESCAPE_PROPERTY, "false");
```

Comment: And where would you set these?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. It seems like if you set the System Property to false, it removes the escaping from the ENTIRE log... From what I can tell, the report is generated after the test, with whatever the system property is set to at the time. I want to insert the screenshot (which worked with above code) but I do not want to remove the other formatting (br tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
Reporter.log("<br>Chrome driver launched for ClassOne</br>");
```

Or you can use customize method, where you do not need to append the br tag everytime, use following customized method.

`public void customLogReport(String testCaseDescription) throws Exception{
        try{
            Reporter.log("<br>" + testCaseDescription + "</br>");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`